# Where does Helena get Kira's letter?

Tags: orphan-black

In Season 1 of *Orphan Black* (I believe it was in S01E07), Helena spends some time looking at, re-reading, and obsessing over a letter from Kira to Sara.

While Helena and Sara have encountered each other before at this point, I can't figure out how Helena got the letter. It's not something that Sara would have willingly given her.

**Where/how did Helena get the letter from Kira to Sara?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In S1E7, "Parts Developed in an Unusual Manner", Helena and Sarah pose as each other to escape the Neolution nightclub. To do so, they switch coats. Sarah gets Helena's parka and Helena gets Sarah's leather jacket.

In S1E8, "Entangled Bank", around the 11 minute mark, we see Helena exploring the jacket. In one of its pockets, she finds Kira's letter.